# Add Cron Job in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

I would like to run this script from a cron job.

I have url for this action www.abc.com/leads/generatedailyreport

I want to run every day this URL to be hit so that my programe will run. Please help.

```
 public function generatedailyreport() {

     $this->Lead->unbindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Country','State','City','Course')), true);
     $currentDate=date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
     $previousDate=date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime('-1 day'));

    // find Each Unniverty
    // Find all the university
    Controller::loadModel('University');
    $University = new University();
    $UniversityArray=$University->find('all',array(
         'conditions'=>array('University.status'=>1),
         'recursive'=>-1));

    //First Row of the xls file
    $listDetails[]=array('Name','Email Address','Contact Number','Query Text','University Name','Source','Created Date');
    $i=1;
    foreach($UniversityArray as $value)
    {

         $UniversityId=$value['University']['id'];
         $university_name=$value['University']['university_code'];
         $universityName=$value['University']['university_name'];
         $leadsDetails=array();
         $leadsDetails=$this->Lead->find('all',array(
             'conditions'=>array(
                                 'Lead.created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '.DAY_INTERVAL.' DAY)  AND CURDATE() ',
                                 //'Lead.created BETWEEN "'.$currentDate.'" AND "'.$previousDate.'"',
                                 'Lead.master_lead_type_id'=>0,
                                 'Lead.university_id'=>$UniversityId,
                     ),
             'fields' => array('COUNT(*) as TotalLeads','University.university_name','Lead.created'),
             'group' => array('Lead.university_id'), 
             'recursive'=>1
             ));

        //pr($leadsDetails);

        if(!empty($leadsDetails)){
            $totalLeads=$leadsDetails[0][0]['TotalLeads'];
            $AssignedUniversityName=$leadsDetails[0]['University']['university_name'];
            $QueryDate=date('d M, Y',strtotime($leadsDetails[0]['Lead']['created']));

            //Total Report Array
            $reportTotalArray[]=array(
                'University_Name'=>$AssignedUniversityName,
                'Total Lead'=>$totalLeads,
                'Date'=>$QueryDate,
                );
        }else{
            $totalLeads='';
            $AssignedUniversityName='';
            $QueryDate='';

        }

        if($totalLeads >0 ){
        $leadsFullDetails=array();
        $leadsFullDetails=$this->Lead->find('all',array(
             'conditions'=>array(
                                 'Lead.created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)  AND CURDATE() ',
                                 //'Lead.created BETWEEN "'.$currentDate.'" AND "'.$previousDate.'"',
                                 'Lead.master_lead_type_id'=>0,
                                 'Lead.university_id'=>$UniversityId,
                     ),
             'fields' => array( 'Lead.first_name',
                                'Lead.email_address',
                                'Lead.contact_number',
                                'Lead.query_text',
                                'Lead.registered_from_source',
                                'University.university_name',
                                'Lead.created'),
             'recursive'=>1
             ));

        // Creating XLS File and send it to Email
        // Find all the leads from respective university
        //pr($leadsFullDetails);
        if(!empty($leadsFullDetails))
        {
            foreach($leadsFullDetails as $data)
            {
                $listDetails[]=array(
                            $data['Lead']['first_name'],
                            $data['Lead']['email_address'],
                            $data['Lead']['contact_number'],
                            $data['Lead']['query_text'],
                            $data['University']['university_name'],
                            $data['Lead']['registered_from_source'],
                            $data['Lead']['created'],
                            );
            }
            //Make an array of all Leads
            $allLeadsArray[$universityName]=$listDetails;

            $filename='Lead_query_'.$university_name.'_'.time().'-'.date('y-m-d',strtotime($data['Lead']['created'])).'.xls';   
            $fp = fopen('../webroot/files/'.$filename, 'w');
            $fileNamexls='../webroot/files/'.$filename;
            foreach ($listDetails as $fields) 
            {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t", '"');
            }
            $listDetails[]=array('Name','Email Address','Contact Number','Query Text','University Name','Source','Created Date');
            fclose($fp);

            // Sending Emails with attachement
            $message="Total Lead Query: ".$totalLeads."\n\r";
            $message_2 ="Assigned University Name: ".$AssignedUniversityName;
            $message_3 ="Query Date: ".$QueryDate;
            $this->set('message',$message);
            $this->set('message_2',$message_2);
            $this->set('message_3',$message_3);

            if($UniversityId==1){
                $toEmail=UOL_EIILM_EMAIL;
                $bccEmailArray=BCC_EMAIL;
                global $ccArrayEIILM;
                $ccArray=$ccArrayEIILM;

            }else if($UniversityId==2){
                $toEmail=UOL_JRU_EMAIL;
                $bccEmailArray=BCC_EMAIL;
                global $ccArrayJRU;
                $ccArray=$ccArrayJRU;

            }else if($UniversityId==3){
                $toEmail=UOL_RAITECH_EMAIL;
                $bccEmailArray=BCC_EMAIL;
                global $ccArrayRAITECH;
                $ccArray=$ccArrayRAITECH;

            }else if($UniversityId==4){
                $toEmail=UOL_NIILM_EMAIL;
                $bccEmailArray=BCC_EMAIL;
                global $ccArrayNIILM;
                $ccArray=$ccArrayNIILM;

            }else if($UniversityId==5){
                $toEmail=UOL_RAI_EMAIL;
                $bccEmailArray=BCC_EMAIL;
                global $ccArrayRAI;
                $ccArray=$ccArrayRAI;

            }else if($UniversityId==6){
                $toEmail=UOL_IUC_EMAIL;
                $bccEmailArray=BCC_EMAIL;
                global $ccArrayIUC;
                $ccArray=$ccArrayIUC;

            }

            $this->Email->to =$toEmail;
            $this->Email->cc = array($ccArray);
            $this->Email->bcc = array($bccEmailArray);
            $this->Email->subject = 'Daily Query Report';
            $this->Email->replyTo = 'no-reply@iuc.org.in';
            $this->Email->from ='Daily_Report@iuc.org.in';
            $this->Email->template = 'daily_report'; // note no '.ctp'
            $this->Email->attachments =array($fileNamexls);
            $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
            $this->Email->send();   
            $message='';
            $totalLeads='';
            $AssignedUniversityName='';
            $QueryDate='';
            $fileNamexls='';
            $ccArray='';
            $toEmail='';
            $listDetails='';

        }
    }

    $i++;
    }
    pr($allLeadsArray);

    // Send Final Email to Mr, Rai
    //pr($reportTotalArray);

    $message='';
    if(!empty($reportTotalArray)){
    foreach($reportTotalArray as $reportData){
        $message.="Assigned University Name: ".$reportData['University_Name'];
        $message.="<br/>";
        $message.="Total Lead Query: ".$reportData['Total Lead'];
        $message.="<br/>";
        $message.="Query Date: ".$reportData['Date'];
        $message.="<br/>";
        $message.="<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
    }
    //echo $message;
    $this->set('totalReport',$message);


    $leadsTotalFullDetails=$this->Lead->find('all',array(
             'conditions'=>array(
                                 'Lead.created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)  AND CURDATE() ',
                                 //'Lead.created BETWEEN "'.$currentDate.'" AND "'.$previousDate.'"',
                                 'Lead.master_lead_type_id'=>0
                     ),
             'fields' => array( 'Lead.first_name',
                                'Lead.email_address',
                                'Lead.contact_number',
                                'Lead.query_text',
                                'Lead.registered_from_source',
                                'University.university_name',
                                'Lead.created'),
             'recursive'=>1
             ));


        // Creating XLS File and send it to Email
        // Find all the leads from respective university
        //pr($leadsFullDetails);
        if(!empty($leadsTotalFullDetails))
        {

            foreach($allLeadsArray as $key=>$dataAll){
                $listAllDetailss[]=array($key,'','Total Lead-',count($dataAll),'','','','');
                $listAllDetailss[]=array('Name','Email Address','Contact Number','Query Text','University Name','Source','Created Date');
                foreach($dataAll as $leadsData){
                    $listAllDetailss[]=$leadsData;
                }
                $listAllDetailss[]=array('','','','','','','');
                $listAllDetailss[]=array('','','','','','','');
                $listAllDetailss[]=array('','','','','','','');
            }

            //$listAllDetails[]=array('Name','Email Address','Contact Number','Query Text','University Name','Source','Created Date');
            /*  
            foreach($leadsTotalFullDetails as $datas)
            {

            $listAllDetails[]=array(
                            $datas['Lead']['first_name'],
                            $datas['Lead']['email_address'],
                            $datas['Lead']['contact_number'],
                            $datas['Lead']['query_text'],
                            $datas['University']['university_name'],
                            $datas['Lead']['registered_from_source'],
                            $datas['Lead']['created'],
                            );
            }
            */
            $allfilename='LeadAllReport_'.time().'-'.date('y-m-d',strtotime($data['Lead']['created'])).'.xls';  
            $fpp = fopen('../webroot/files/'.$allfilename, 'w');
            $fileNamexls='../webroot/files/'.$allfilename;
            foreach ($listAllDetailss as $fieldss) 
            {
                fputcsv($fpp, $fieldss, "\t", '"');
            }

            fclose($fpp);

        $this->Email->to =ALL_TO_EMAIL;
        $this->Email->cc = array(ALL_TO_CC);
        $this->Email->bcc = array(ALL_TO_BCC);
        $this->Email->subject = 'Daily Query Report';
        $this->Email->replyTo = 'no-reply@iuc.org.in';
        $this->Email->from ='Daily_Report@iuc.org.in';
        $this->Email->template = 'daily_report_total'; // note no '.ctp'
        $this->Email->attachments =array($fileNamexls);
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
        $this->Email->send();   

        // Delete All files after sending on emails
        echo "$i Mail Sent.";
    }
}
    die;

}
```

Comment: You probably want to use something like curl to fetch the page every day. You may be better off asking somewhere like [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/); this isn't really very programming-related.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Shell` script.
You don't want bots or other people to access your cron directly in the url.

Shells are created in `App/Console/Command`.

If you have ssh access, use the `crontab`, where you need to add something like:

```
0 9 * * * /var/www/site.com/vendors/cakeshell myShell -app myApp
```

[More info here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html)

Comment: Please let me knwo the sell script, I am using CAKE PHP 2.3.0

Comment: Can you check this page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html and set up that script as a cron? Then try to add it to crontab? I cannot give a more clear example, other than the officual documentation

Comment: I have seen their documentaion but can;t able to write script.

Comment: The get somebody who is? The code provided in the question is pretty bad as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `cakePHP` work.. You can do it by using your `cpanel` from your `hosting`.. In your `cpanel` find `crond jobs` or `scheduled tasks`.. from there you have to put your desired `file path` and as well the `timings` for your `cronjob`..
and if your hosing provider doesnt provide cron jobs than you can use `putty` to create cronjobs..

http://php-opensource-help.blogspot.in/2010/03/how-to-set-up-cron-job-file-using-putty.html

let me explain you in brief.

It doesnt matter weather your cron job is written in corephp or cakephp.. 
cron jobs are scheduled tasks which fire automatically from your server on the desired time which is set for that particular cronjob..

you need to ask to your hosting provider that you want to `setup a cron job` on your server. and they will guide you further...

Comment: No from cron jon we can't find any page for this URL
www.abc.com/leads/generatedailyreport
I want to this URL , let me know what are the methods to hit this URL everyday automatically

Comment: When I hit a URL "www.mywebsite.com/leads/generatedailyreport" 
this will send all the daily reports to different different email address, now i want to run this script using cron job, due to CAKE PHP i can't able to set into cron this URL, because cron needs atleast one file with extendsion .php, now let me knwo what are the methods so that I can set this URL into cron.

Comment: yes I got it.. But you just concentrate on my answer.. I have provided you the right answer.. You doesnt need cakephp to fire `cronjobs` you need a cpanel with cronjob support...

Answer (score 1):

HELLO frnd you can easily create cron jon in cake php

```
        class HelloShell extends AppShell 
        {
        public $uses=array('Jobs','JobFeeds','JobMapping','User');

             public function main() 
             {
               $this->out('Hello world.');
             }

    }
```

this is file i have put in app/console/command/HelloShell.php

i have the command in my ubantu terminal.
          $ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/JobFinder/app/     than enter

```
      /opt/lampp/htdocs/JobFinder/app$ crontab -e
```

this will open command line like this

```
     */1  *   *    *   *  cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/JobFinder/app && Console/cake hello $

    # Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
    #
    # Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
    # indicating with different fields when the task will be run
    # and what command to run for the task
    #
    # To define the time you can provide concrete values for
    # minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
    # and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
    # Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
    # daemon's notion of time and timezones.
    #
    # Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
    # email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
    #
    # For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
    # at 5 a.m every week with:
                                  [ Unknown Command ]
    ^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
    ^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell
```

you have set the timer for what task you want to done

```
public function insert()
    {
        App::import('Utility', 'Xml');
      //    $this->loadModel('Jobs');
        $this->Jobs->deleteAll(array('1 = 1'));

        $AllUrls=$this->JobFeeds->find('all');
        if(is_array($AllUrls) && count($AllUrls)>0 )
        {
            foreach($AllUrls as $urls)
            {
                $xml = Xml::build($urls['JobFeeds']['url']);
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);die;
                $cat_id=$urls['JobFeeds']['job_category_id'];
                $feed_id=$urls['JobFeeds']['id'];
                foreach($xml as $items)
                {
                    foreach($items->item as $job)
                    {

                        App::import('Model', 'JobMapping');
                        $this->JobMapping = new JobMapping();
                        $AllData=$this->JobMapping->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('JobMapping.job_feeds_id'=>$feed_id)));

                        App::import('Model', 'Jobs');
                        $this->Jobs = new Jobs();
                       foreach($AllData as $allData)
                        {
                            $data['title']      =$job->$allData['JobMapping']['title'];
                            $data['description']=$job->$allData['JobMapping']['description'];
                            $data['link']       =$job->$allData['JobMapping']['link'];
                            $data['guid']       =$job->$allData['JobMapping']['guid'];
                            $data['pubDate']    =$job->$allData['JobMapping']['pubDate'];
                            $data['Updated_date']= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                            $data['inserted_date']= date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
                            $data['cat_id']     =$cat_id;
                            //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
                            $this->Jobs->save($data);
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }


    }
```

in this code i have inserted data within 1 min in database(will update automatically my my job table`enter code here`)

A common thing to do with a shell is making it run as a cronjob to clean up the database once in a while or send newsletters. This is trivial to setup, for example:

```
  */5  *    *    *    *  cd /full/path/to/app && Console/cake myshell myparam
# *    *    *    *    *  command to execute
# │    │    │    │    │
# │    │    │    │    │
# │    │    │    │    \───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday,
  |    |    |    |           or use names)
# │    │    │    \────────── month (1 - 12)
# │    │    \─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │    \──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# \───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```